# Banding on object with Blend Mode: Color Dodge but not on Gradient Background

Tags: gradient, opacity, adobe-illustrator, blend-mode

I've got a piece of artwork with a gradient background with no banding. On top of the background are a moon and stars I've  I've colored yellow and used "color dodge" to blend over the background. For some reason, the moon has a banding/pixellation problem. I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried rasterizing, but that just flattened it back into opaque yellow. I don't know how to make it look smooth. The other objects with opacity are not doing the same thing when placed over the gradient.
[image]

You can see the sun (color: red, blend mode: overlay) is blending nice and smooth, but the moon looks pixellated.

[image]

[image]

How can I make the gradient in the moon look smooth like the rest of the artwork?

Comment: Try to ask here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator

Comment: I can reproduce the problem but I don't know how it can be solved. Probably it's a glitch of the mode 'color dodge'. I'd just avoid to use the mode for now for such cases. Actually this image can be done just fine without the 'color dodge'.

Comment: Actually the question is not about coding, so it doesn't belong Stackoverflow. And with no any reaction for five days it looks abandoned. Vote to close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this here, I'm new to the community and didn't know there was another place I should ask. I didn't close it because no one offered a solution yet. What I ended up doing was using the moon shape as a clipping mask over a rectangle with the correct color gradient. I could not figure out how to solve this issue. I don't know how to "close" the question. Sorry it's in the wrong place.